# UIWebView slides down when tilting iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

In the simulator this does not seem to happen, because you can't tilt the simulator.

When I run a UIWebView on my device and tilt it seems to slide down and leave a gap of 44px, it seems to be the height of the NavigationBar at the top.

I don't have any code to post as I do not what is causing this.
When I go to another view and come back to this, the gap is gone as the iPhone didn't move between appearing.

Any ideas on what to do to stop this behavior?

I am using iOS 6 and Storyboard, if I can post anything to help, please let me know.

[image]

I have posted a screen shot from my device to show what is actually happen.

Comment: You can simulate device rotation in the simulator cmd-right or cmd-left arrows.  Is it really a little tilt, or rotation?  If it's just a tilt, then you've discovered an unheard of mode of failure as far as I know.

Comment: Yeah it does not happen on rotation - neither the device or the simulator. so I find this really weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this can happen because of Auto Layout there might be a constraint that set it 44px below, 
Check it out 
Hope this will help ,
Further you can get the basic idea about AutoLayout feature from Ray Wenderlitch site http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Comment: That one makes sense - I will work on it and update the answer